2038 Bug | How to handle on a yocto builded 32Bit System
I'm encountering some issues while working with Yocto and Linux kernel configuration to address the Year 2038 problem.
What i did so far:

Added : TARGET_CPPFLAGS += "-D_TIME_BITS=64 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64"
Patched: zlib _TimeBits - explained here:stackoverflow

After these changes, I was able to get a running system and change the time with the date command. At first glance, everything looked good.
However, I noticed some strange timestamps in /var/log/messages and encountered issues connecting to a PostgreSQL database, receiving a "connection refused" error, among others.
Jan  1 00:00:10 XXX daemon.info avahi-daemon[1696]: Server startup complete. Host name is XXX.local. Local service cookie is 1686369141.
Dec 31 23:59:59 XXX daemon.err collectd[1697]: network plugin: sendto failed: Cannot assign requested address. Closing sending socket.
Aug 14 10:31:47 XXX daemon.info avahi-daemon[1696]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface docker0.IPv4 with address 172.17.0.1.
Jan 22 10:32:00 XXX daemon.info avahi-daemon[1696]: New relevant interface docker0.IPv4 for mDNS.
May  5 06:36:58 XXX daemon.info avahi-daemon[1696]: Registering new address record for 172.17.0.1 on docker0.IPv4.
Dec 31 23:59:59 XXX daemon.err collectd[1697]: network plugin: sendto failed: Cannot assign requested address. Closing sending socket.
Dec 31 23:59:59 XXX daemon.err collectd[1697]: network plugin: sendto failed: Cannot assign requested address. Closing sending socket.
Dec 31 23:59:59 XXX daemon.err collectd[1697]: network plugin: sendto failed: Cannot assign requested address. Closing sending socket.

So i decided to :

disable Provide system calls for 32-bit time_t
(includes) disable CONFIG_COMPAT_32BIT_TIME

This change led to a kernel panic:
[    6.808240] systemd[1]: System time before build time, advancing clock.
[    6.836919] Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000004

Kernel Configuration:

Are there any other kernel configuration options I might have missed
that are necessary for enabling 64-bit time support?

Glibc Configuration:

Is there anything specific I need to check or configure in Glibc
beyond what I’ve already done?

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Background


Platform: i.MX6UL
System: Yocto-based
Kernel Version: 5.10.47
Systemd: 250.5+
Glibc Version: 2.35


